# VBA code to clear contents of cell A and B if cells C blank when macro runs from another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to clear extra cells of column A and B if find blank cells in column C of sheet named `Sold` and Macro runs from Sheet named `Invoice`.

I got below code from a helping site but cannot get my desired result.Below attached is the screenshot of desired output

```
Sum Clear()

Dim g As Long
For g = 2 To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
If Cells(g, "C").Value = "" Then
Cells(g, "A").ClearContents
Cells(g, "B").ClearContents 

End If
Next
End Sum
```

[image: Desired Result]

Comment: I think either AutoFilter or SpecialCells would save you from any iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like :

```
Sub Sample()
 '============ Init ================
 Dim Ws_Sold As Worksheet
 Set Ws_Sold = Sheets("Sold")
 Dim count As Integer
 count = 1
 Dim lastrow As Long
 lastrow = Ws_Sold.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row 
 'give number of the last cell not empty

 '============ loop================
 While (count < lastrow + 1)
    If Ws_Sold.Cells(count, 3).Value = "" Then
        Ws_Sold.Cells(count, 1).ClearContents
        Ws_Sold.Cells(count, 2).ClearContents    
    End If
    count = count + 1
 Wend
```

End Sub

Have a nice day !

Comment: It worked for me fine, Thanks for Immediate feedback and co-operate. You save my day. Have a Nice Day Dear

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the name of the sheet.

```
Sub Clear()
Dim g As Long
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sold")
    For g = 2 To .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        If .Cells(g, "C").Value = "" Then
            .Cells(g, "A").ClearContents
            .Cells(g, "B").ClearContents
        End If
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This work fine for me, i got that point. You save me. Have Good Day

Answer (score 0):

**Non VBA Way**

you can put formula `=IF(LEN(TRIM(C2))=0,"",POPULATETHISCELL)` in the cells `A` and `B` where you can replace **POPULATETHISCELL** with whatever you are trying to get there. For example, populating today's date.

**VBA Way**

1. Work with `Objects`. Avoid the use of `ActiveWorkbook/Activesheet/Selection` etc as show [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)
2. Avoid the use of `UsedRange`. Find last row as shown [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) and then loop through it.
3. Instead of clearing ranges twice, you can clear it in one go as shown below

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sold")

    With ws
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
            lastrow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                          After:=.Range("A1"), _
                          Lookat:=xlPart, _
                          LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                          MatchCase:=False).Row

            For i = 2 To lastrow
                If Len(Trim(.Range("C" & i).Value)) = 0 Then _
                .Range("A" & i & ":B" & i).ClearContents
            Next i
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This work fine for me, Thanks for Immediate feedback. You save me. Have Good Day